# Refer to a Property name using a Variable in Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, properties

I am trying to access a property "DailyQtyOrders_01" in my object using the first code below, this works ok.
but now i want to use it in a linq expression on the second line code, this works, but i want the property to be variable (3rd line code), this throws error. What is the method to do that?

```
item.GetType().GetProperty("DailyQtyOrders_01").SetValue(item, 5);

productsSales.Where(x => x.sellerId == item.sellerId).FirstOrDefault().DailyQtyOrders_01 = 5;


productsSales.Where(x => x.sellerId == item.sellerId).FirstOrDefault().item.GetType().GetProperty("DailyQtyOrders_01").SetValue(item, 5);
```

Comment: What is item (in the last method)? Shouldn't you just use `?.GetType()` on the returned item, if any (`var myItem = productsSales.Where(x => x.sellerId == item.sellerId).FirstOrDefault(); myItem?.GetType().GetProperty("DailyQtyOrders_01").SetValue(myItem, 5);`)?  Do you really need to access a property by name?

Comment: The linq statement is inside a foreach( var item in Orders) , and I want to change the property value, so yes I need to access by name.

Comment: It's not that you *need* to, that's how you coded it to be. Iterate the properties and use the snippet in the first comment to set the current property to the current value using the property name. If you know where `5` comes from. Is it the property value of the item used for the comparison? Maybe, post the whole code if this doesn't apply.

Comment: @bobmason There’s more than one kind of error. Which one?

Answer (score 1):

First of all if this code is run in any sort of loop, you have to be careful you dont run into performance issues.

When you enter the areas of `.GetType()`,`.GetProperty()` and `.SetProperty()` you are doing reflection, which really shouldn't be nessesary.

It's hard to see from your code example but the Order that you have in your item should really be changable from `item.DailyQtyOrders_01` directly. Also if you really want to use strings and reflection, which i cannot recommend in any way, you can at least use strongly typed ways to achieve this (which makes sure your code doesn't break on a refactor)

That would make this code:

```
item.GetType().GetProperty("DailyQtyOrders_01").SetValue(item, 5)
```

Look like this instead:

```
item.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Order.DailyQtyOrders_01)).SetValue(item, 5)
```

available from c# 6.0 and forward, `nameof` can be used on classes and properties and so on to get the string, but avoiding the actual string, that you might not catch in a rename.

Comment: If you really need to access a property by name from a variable, you should consider dynamically compiling out an accessor `Func`/`Action` to cache out the IL required to the property access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the last part of your third linq statement.

```
productsSales.Where(x => x.sellerId == item.sellerId).FirstOrDefault().item.GetType().GetProperty("DailyQtyOrders_01").SetValue(item, 5);
```

In the above code, you are assigning the value of "DailyQtyOrders_01" in an instance of "item". This is not the same instance of your linq query refers to, but the variable "item" you have created/referred above.

```
.GetProperty("DailyQtyOrders_01").SetValue(item, 5);
```

What you need to do would be to split the query into two parts, and refer the instance on which you want the value to be set.

For example

```
var itemInstance =  productsSales.Where(x => x.sellerId == item.sellerId).FirstOrDefault().item;
itemInstance.GetType().GetProperty("DailyQtyOrders_01").SetValue(itemInstance, 5);
productsSales.Where(x => x.sellerId == item.sellerId).FirstOrDefault().item = itemInstance;
```